# Variável ficar arredondando e estraga calculo

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho o seguinte SELECT:

```
SET @peso := 0;
SET @ganho := 0;

SELECT
    @peso := (SELECT SUM(peso)/1000 FROM entrada WHERE entrada_id = A.entrada_id)+@ganho AS peso,
    @peso,
    @ganho := (SELECT SUM(ganho)/1000 FROM entrada WHERE entrada_id = A.entrada_id) AS ganho,
    @ganho
FROM
    entrada AS A
WHERE
    A.entrada_id IN (18, 19,20, 21,22)
GROUP BY
    A.entrada_id
```

Eu começo o "peso" e o "ganho" com 0 e tenho que aplicar a soma do peso + ganho pra cada linha que estiver voltando.

Os meus problema são dois:

1. A variável quando eu coloco em uma coluna apenas mostra o resultado como um número inteiro e não como um decimal, eu preciso do decimal pro calculo.
2. Acho que uma vez que não esta voltando o decimal, ele ta bagunçando o calculo.

Alguém sabe o motivo do MYSQL arredondar a variável na coluna já que o resultado é um decimal?

Resultado da query abaixo:

```
 peso           @peso  ganho        @ganho
 852.1890056    852    0.031025076  0
 852.1889198    852    1.714096448  1
 853.8719912    854    2.465015896  2
 854.6229106    856    2.83135176   2
```

Comment: As variáveis são `decimal` ou `float`?

Comment: Você esta declarando as viaveis como float ou real?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Estou declando no começo do select com: SET @ peso := 0 ;
SET @ ganho := 0;

Comment: @LuizSantos No começo do meu select eu faço isto usando o SET. Quando fala em float ou real, poderia me dar um exemplo? Obrigado.

Comment: dado, texta la por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução:

```
SET @in_weight = CAST(0 AS decimal(10,10));
SET @daily_gain := CAST(0 AS decimal(10,10)) ;
```

Comment: boa!!! :) desculpa a confusão anterior

Comment: @LuizSantos Relaxa. Tudo certo. Obrigado pela atenção. Abraço.